# SSO login error with Salesforce

Tags: single-sign-on, login-errors

I received following error

"We can't log you in because of an issue with single sign-on. Contact your Salesforce admin for help"

when I try to login to Salesforce via SSO.

I have setup SSO with federation id , updated certificate and user record. Error still appears. I am not able to see the logs as well.

Can someone suggest how to proceed with this?

Comment: Look at the page where this error occurs - in the url, it generally has the error number/description which will help you debug what is going on.

Comment: URL ended with /saml/SamlError. Issue was with the domain name at IDP end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom domain name at IDP end was incorrect. SSO started working after fixing the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

When I receive this specific error, I've often forgotten to add a **Profile** or **Permission Set** from the **"Manage"** connected app page.

Hope this will help someone else out!

[image: Profiles or Permission Sets from Manage page]